# Are there concerns with doing a generalized additive model with a smoothing term of multiple variables?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

In R, usually one performs a generalized additive model like so:

```
library(mgcv)
x <- gam(depvar ~ s(indvar1) + s(indvar2) + parametricvar)
```

Say I want to explore the non-parametric interaction of `indvar1` and `indvar2`.

Is the following kosher? Are there issues of statistical validity with implementing such a model?

```
x <- gam(depvar ~ s(indvar,indvar2) + parametricvar)
```